# Unable to map an array from another array with changed values

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array, `grpList` contains unique id's & unique names.

```
grpList = [
  { name: "grp1", id: "1" },
  { name: "grp2", id: "2" },
  { name: "grp3", id: "3" },
  { name: "grp4", id: "4" },
  { name: "grp5", id: "5" },
  { name: "grp6", id: "6" }
]
```

Another type of Array, In the below array **currentList**, it has only 2 types i.e `G` or `Q`, with type `'G'` it has array values with unique names. These names are mapped from the `grpList` Array.

```
currentList = [
  { name: "name1", type: "G", values: ["grp1", "grp3"] },
  { name: "name2", type: "Q", values:"abcd" },
  { name: "name3", type: "G", values: ["grp1", "grp5"] },
  { name: "name4", type: "Q", values:"frd" },
  { name: "name5", type: "G", values: ["grp1", "grp2"] },
  { name: "name6", type: "Q", values:"erer" }
]
```

Now What I want is that create a new array that consist data of type `currentList` i.e it should contains properties of `currentList` array and it should mapped with ids corresponding to `grpList` array.

Example:

```
newArry = [
      { name: "name1", type: "G", values: ["1", "3"] },
      { name: "name2", type: "Q", values:"abcd" },
      { name: "name3", type: "G", values: ["1", "5"] },
      { name: "name4", type: "Q", values:"frd" },
      { name: "name5", type: "G", values: ["1", "2"] },
      { name: "name6", type: "Q", values:"erer" }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```js
const grpList = [
  { name: "grp1", id: "1" },
  { name: "grp2", id: "2" },
  { name: "grp3", id: "3" },
  { name: "grp4", id: "4" },
  { name: "grp5", id: "5" },
  { name: "grp6", id: "6" }
];

const currentList = [
  { name: "name1", type: "G", values: ["grp1", "grp3"] },
  { name: "name2", type: "Q", values:"abcd" },
  { name: "name3", type: "G", values: ["grp1", "grp5"] },
  { name: "name4", type: "Q", values:"frd" },
  { name: "name5", type: "G", values: ["grp1", "grp2"] },
  { name: "name6", type: "Q", values:"erer" }
]

const newList = currentList.map(item => {
  if (item.type == 'Q') return item;
  const values = item.values.map(value => {
    const grpItem = grpList.find(grp => grp.name == value);
    return grpItem.id;
  })
  return {...item, values}
});

console.log(newList)
```

Comment: This is returning me all the ids in every array

Comment: what do you mean? the `newList` is the same as your expected result. doesn't it?

Comment: yeah, you are correct ! Thank you.

Comment: can you upvote my question ? few people are taking revenge because I have not accepted their answers.

Comment: @user8348978 I did it already. I really don't know why several people give the questio downvote.

Comment: @SaeedShamloo Because the question doesn't fulfil the standards: _"Don't ask about...

    Questions you haven't tried to find an answer for (show your work!)"_ [tour] That's a common reason to downvote and delete questions for many users. Your answer risks the same because it doesn't contain a description. Code-only answers are often considered bad.

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over each value in each element and remove `grp` with a `replace`:

```js
const currentList = [
  { name: "name1", type: "G", values: ["grp1", "grp3"] },
  { name: "name2", type: "Q", values:"abcd" },
  { name: "name3", type: "G", values: ["grp1", "grp5"] },
  { name: "name4", type: "Q", values:"frd" },
  { name: "name5", type: "G", values: ["grp1", "grp2"] },
  { name: "name6", type: "Q", values:"erer" }
];

const result = currentList.map(el => {
  if (!Array.isArray(el.values) || el.type !== 'G') return el;
  return {...el, values: el.values.map(v => v.replace('grp', ''))};
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: This `grp1` can be any arbitary name

Comment: @user8348978 I answered your question, and you didn't mention this in your question.

Comment: can you submit your answer with the current scenario ?

Comment: @user8348978 Why? You already have a correct and accepted answer. Isn't that enough? My answer still answers the posted question, although that's not what you meant to ask.

Comment: okay thank you, for your kind words. Thank you for helping.